Issue with configuring python packages with poetry
I want to configure a python package with poetry for better dependency management, for some reason it connot find the any packages i mention as it should, I am new to using poetry so I want to know how to solve this issue...
This is what I did, I already had a python project that is supposed to be configured into a package..
so I did cd package_dir in powershell and did poetry init and the rest is down in the image


The issue is with pip here, after skimming through poetry's issues i found an issue raised last week regarding this, it seems that this interactive package adding feature uses pip's search command pip search and pip has stopped supporting it, that is why it was broken, so soon a fix will made and this issue will resolved.
